# Can't insert data to mysql database using browser though running in cli does everything rightly

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to insert data into a mysql database using standard sql through form.
my code is as follows:

```
<?php
$name="";
$ename="";
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $er = 0;
    if($name=="")
    {
        $er++;
        $ename = "Required";
    }
    else if(strlen($name)<2 || strlen($name)>200)
    {
        $er++;
        $ename = "Name must contain 3-300 characters";
    }
    if($er==0)
    {
        $cn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbuscoaching");
        $sql="INSERT INTO city (name,countryId) VALUES('".strip_tags($name)."',".$country.")";
        if(mysqli_query($cn,$sql))
        {
            print '<span class= "successMessage">Country Inserted to Database</span>';
            $name="";
        }
        else
        {
            print '<span class="errorMessage">'.mysqli_error($cn).'</span>';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        print '<span class="errorMessage" >You have some problems in your form</span>';
    }
}

?>
<form method="post" action="">
    <label>Name</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php print $name; ?>">
    <span class="error" id="ename"><?php print $ename; ?></span>
    <br>
    <label>Country</label><br>
    <select name="country" id="country">
        <option value="0">Select</option>
        <?php
        $cn= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbuscoaching");
        $sql="select id, name from country";
        $table=mysqli_query($cn,$sql);
        while ($row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($table))
        {
            print '<option value="'.$row["id"].'">'.$row["name"].'</option>';
        }
        ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

When running in browser i'm getting this error message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ')' at line 1

but in cli php the code runs with no error as shown bellow:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <label>Name</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="">
    <span class="error" id="ename"></span>
<br />
    <label>Country</label><br>
    <select name="country" id="country">
        <option value="0">Select</option>
       <option value="1">Bangladesh</option><option value="2">USA</option><option value="3">India</option><option value="4">Bhutan</option><option value="5">Maldives</option><option value="6">Nepal</option><option value="7">UK</option><option value="8">Australlia</option><option value="9"></option><option value="10">Japan</option><option value="11">Iran</option>    </select>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
Process finished with exit code 0
```

though i'm following what my instructor told i'm getting this error.
can you please tell me what's the problem?

Comment: Echo out your SQL, and look at it for syntax errors. Additionally, if you use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php), you'll never have to worry about quoting your variables again (and it prevents SQL injection).

Comment: the cgi doesn't post the form..

Comment: You're not submitting the country as a string `".$country."` should be `'".$country."'` Having said that, you need to follow @aynber's advice.

Comment: I'm new to php. i'm just learning the basics. Do i need to learn those techniques so early?

Comment: Yes, you must learn them early so you do not develop bad habits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not assign any value to the `$country` variable, hence the actual sql statement looks like sg like as follows (this is why you should print out the actual sql statement, the error would be obvious):

```
INSERT INTO city (name,countryId) VALUES('whatever you typed in as name',)
```

Since there is nothing ahead of the closing parentheses, MySQL reports a syntax error. You need to assign value to `$country` variable:

```
$country=$_POST['country'];
```

However, pls try to avoid creating a query string through simple string concatenation. Use prepared statements with parameters.